# java mail- how to send mail where message body is the return table value of a method in the java class

Tags: java, email

i created a jsp page which can filter and retrieve data from database in form of table through java and calculate some variables, where my dynamic tables are in java file and filter for displaying reports in jsp. now the problem is  i want to include the  html table in the java class   in my message body.so my message body display the table content of report.  how can fetch the java table in the message body?.

i have created the html table structure in the email body but the values are not displaying in the table.

Comment: Please include the code you tried and the output it produces in the question text.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask], show the (relevant!) code you have so far and also check whether you've set the content type of the email to `text/html`. Finally, note that not every email client displays html messages (by default).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use JSPs to generate e-mails.
Try another template engine such as velocity, thymeleaf, or freemarker.